# Log on to site using powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, https

I am trying to log on to an https site using a powershell script.

I've tried using a PSCredential, but I get a 401 unauthorized error when I do.

I am providing the username and password in the script. I want it to log me in without being prompted.

What is the best way to do this? Is it best to use an httprequest?

Here's what I have so far.

```
$userName = "username"
$secure_password = ConvertTo-SecureString "my password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName,         $secure_password)
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "url_for_the_download" -Credential $credential
```

Comment: You're not telling us if you're trying to use a web service, if you're trying to perform some sort of synthetic transaction, etc.  You're also not showing us any sample code.

Comment: Ok. I've added some code above--it's where I'm at so far. I am not trying to call a web service. The url, when copy-pasted into my web browser, brings up a log-in screen and downloads a zip file upon successful logon. I am trying to automate the entire process so that I need only run the script to take care of the whole thing. The site uses basic authentication. Because I am new to Powershell and web technologies, any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass")
$client.DownloadFile("http://somesite.com/somefile.zip","C:\somefile.zip")
```